# Is the space $H_0^2(\Omega)$ the same as $H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the space $H_0^2(\Omega)$ the same as $H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$?
Here $H^k$ is the sobolev space $W^{k,2}$.

Comment: Is $H_0^k(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ for the $H^k(\Omega)$ norm ? What is the dimension of $\Omega$ ?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. The dimension of $\Omega$ is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

In most (all?) situations the answer is no. Heuristically, $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ satisfies $u = 0$ on the boundary while $u \in H_0^2(\Omega)$ satisfies $u = 0$ and $\nabla u = 0$ on the boundary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any counter example?

Comment: Yes, there are many counterexamples. Just take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $u$ with $u = 0$, $\nabla u \ne 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.